# Добавление переменной окружения в Linux при помощи Golang до выхода пользователя из системы

Tags: linux, golang

Как можно добавить переменную окружения при помощи приложения на golang, чтобы она оставалась доступной после завершения работы приложения - до выхода пользователя из системы (аналогично команде export в Linux)?

`os.Setenv` - делает переменную только на время работы программы,
а `exec.Command` - вообще не ставит переменную так, как мне необходимо.

Код:

```
func main() {
    //os.Setenv("LC_TEST", "TEST")
    cmd := exec.Command("export", "LC_TEST=TEST")
    _ = cmd.Run()
    myenv := os.Getenv("LC_TEST")
    fmt.Printf("My test env: %s \n", myenv)
    shellenv := os.Getenv("SHELL")
    fmt.Printf("SHELL = : %s \n", shellenv)
}
```

Вывод:

```
$ ./go_testenv
My test env:
SHELL = : /bin/bash
$ env | grep TEST
$ export LC_TEST2=TEST2
v$ env | grep TEST
LC_TEST2=TEST2
```

Comment: А какую проблему вы хотите решить на самом деле? Чтобы при запуске программы имелось соответствующее окружение? ИМХО это к Ops'ам надо сходить или запускать программу с выставлением переменной окружения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если коротко, то никак.

Если развёрнуто, то окружение наследуется от родителя к потомку, но никак не в обратном направлении. То есть `export` в шелле создаёт переменную в окружении шелла, откуда её наследует запускаемый процесс. Если измените окружение в процессе, это могут увидеть его потомки, но никак не шелл, из которого запущен процесс.

Вы можете добавить переменную в файл профиля `~/.profile` или `~/.bashrc`, но и в этом случае шелл не увидит эту переменную до перезапуска процесса.

`export` - это не программа, а встроенная инструкция шелла, которая обрабатывается особым образом.

**DIRTY DIRTY HACK**

Если вы чувствуете в себе силы на чёрный хакинг, то добавить переменную окружения в родительский шелл таки возможно. Нужно запустить отладчик gdb, приаттачиться к предку вы выполнить команду

```
(gdb) call (int)setenv("SOME_VAR", "some_val", 1)
(gdb) continue
```

затем прервать процесс и отсоединиться (detach) от предка.

Если при этом шелл навернётся и утянет за собой вашу программу... ну что ж, бывает.

Разумеется, нельзя так просто взять и поменять окружение предка. Мне потребовалось запускать `sudo gdb`, для обычного пользователя `attach` отвалился с ошибкой `operation not permitted`. Но переменная поменялась, есть такое.

```
 >$ set | grep ZZZ
 >$ echo $$
13863
 >$ sudo gdb 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1.1-0ubuntu1) 8.1.1
(gdb) attach 13863
Attaching to process 13863
0x00007ffbaacfc457 in __GI___waitpid (pid=-1, stat_loc=0x7ffd6b1040f0, options=10) 
(gdb) call (int)setenv("ZZZ", "xxx", 1)
$1 = 0
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00007ffbaacfc457 in __GI___waitpid (pid=-1, stat_loc=0x7ffd6b1040f0, options=10) 
(gdb) detach
Detaching from program: /bin/bash, process 13863
(gdb) quit
 >$ set | grep ZZZ
ZZZ=xxx
```

Comment: Стандартный, чуть менее дёрти, хак — приложение возвращет команды для шелла и шелл их выполняет через eval. Например `eval "$(starship init bash)"` (пример из документации https://starship.rs/guide/#%F0%9F%9A%80-installation)