# Обновление переменной окружения для запущенного процесса

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, .env

Всем привет. Подскажите, можно ли обновить значение ENV-переменной для уже запущенного процесса без перезапуска самого процесса.

Есть сервер, который работает и обрабатывает запросы. Он ссылается на какую-то переменную окружения, я открываю соседний терминал, прописываю

```bash
export ENV_VAR='Hello world'
```

отправляю запрос на сервер и он мне отвечает новым значением ENV_VAR без принудительной перезагрузки самого сервера.

Если вопрос не сюда, извините.

Comment: Это смотря как сам сервер работает с переменными окружения. Если он их читает один раз при старте, то ничего не сделать. А если он их читает каждый раз из окружения, когда они ему нужны или даже следит за их изменением - это другое дело, тогда это сработает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Переменная окружения записывается в процесс системным вызовом `execve` при создании процесса. После того, как процесс создан, нет никаких стандартных способов изменить извне переменные окружения.

Но если вы чувствуете в себе силы, можете попробовать подключиться к процессу через `gdb` и через вызов функции `setenv` изменить переменную. Подробнее: [Добавление переменной окружения в Linux при помощи Golang до выхода пользователя из системы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1509388/)